# ActionView::MissingTemplate errors on Travis CI (but not locally)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, travis-ci

### Solution

This is a silly one. Git behaves strangely with folders sometimes; changing a folder name isn't a change that gets pushed. On GitHub, my view folder was "Bills" with a capital B, even though it was "bills" locally.

I solved this by renaming my old folder, creating a new "bills" folder, and then moving the contents from old folder to new folder (since moving files is a pushable change). See [this](http://www.patrick-wied.at/blog/rename-files-and-folders-with-git) for more details.

### tl;dr

My tests pass locally and the app seems to work, but all of my tests on one controller are failing with ActionView::MissingTemplate errors, despite the fact the templates appear to be in the right place. Any idea why?

### Problem

I just spent the afternoon refactoring a rails app (most notably, renaming Legislation to Bill), but I'm now having a build issue that I haven't been able to figure out.

When I run my tests locally, they all pass, and clicking around the app works as expected. However, on Travis CI, I get this error (ActionView::MissingTemplate) for everything in my bills_controller_test.rb:

```
Error:
BillsControllerTest#test_: bills should get index. :
ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template bills/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :prawn, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/travis/build/troy-open-data/legislative_twitter/app/views"
  * "/home/travis/build/troy-open-data/legislative_twitter/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/kaminari-0.16.3/app/views"
  * "/home/travis/build/troy-open-data/legislative_twitter/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/foundation-rails-5.5.1.0/app/views"
    test/controllers/bills_controller_test.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <class:BillsControllerTest>'
```

([On Travis](https://travis-ci.org/troy-open-data/legislative_twitter/builds/59915498))

However, the files `app/views/bills/*.html.erb` for each controller action appear to be there. Why can't Travis find them? (Again, the tests in bills_controller_test.rb are the only ones that are failing on Travis and they are passing locally.)

I can't replicate this locally, and my Googling and fiddling with it has been unsuccessful thus far.

### What I've tried

- I've double-checked that all references to bill have the correct pluralization and capitalization (they appear to)–this was my first guess because OS X and Linux sometimes treat capitalization differently.
- I've checked other edits, particularly configuration changes to .travis.yml and test_helper.rb, but neither appear to have caused the problem.
- I've confirmed that bills_controller_test.rb is actually connecting to app/controllers/bills_controller.rb, and it is (the error arrises on the `render: :<action>` at the end of the controller action)

### Relevant code snippets

**test/controllers/bills_controller_test.rb (#index)** ([on GitHub](https://github.com/troy-open-data/legislative_twitter/blob/hardening-refactoring-and-API/test/controllers/bills_controller_test.rb))

```
require 'test_helper'

class BillsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  context 'bills' do
    should 'get index' do
      get :index
      assert_response :success
      assert_not_nil assigns(:bills)
    end
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

**app/controllers/bills_controller.rb (#index)** ([on GitHub](https://github.com/troy-open-data/legislative_twitter/blob/hardening-refactoring-and-API/app/controllers/bills_controller.rb))

```
class BillsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_bill, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /bills
  def index
    @bills = Bill.by_recent
                 .includes(:attachments)
                 .page(params[:page])
  end
  ...
end
```

**routes.rb** ([on GitHub](https://github.com/troy-open-data/legislative_twitter/blob/hardening-refactoring-and-API/config/routes.rb))

```
require 'api_version'  # lib/api_version.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: 'json' } do
    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiVersion.new('v1', true) do
      resources :bills,         only: [:index, :show]
      resources :meetings,      only: [:index, :show]
      scope '/meetings/:id' do
        get '/agenda',  to: 'meetings#agenda',  as: 'agenda'
        get '/minutes', to: 'meetings#minutes', as: 'minutes'
      end
      resources :organizations, only: [:index, :show]
      root to: 'data#index'
    end
  end


  resources :bills
  resources :organizations
  resources :meetings
  scope '/meetings/:id' do
    get '/agenda',  to: 'meetings#agenda', as: 'agenda'
    get '/minutes', to: 'meetings#minutes', as: 'minutes'
    get '/in_progress',  to: 'meetings#start_meeting', as: 'start_meeting'
    get '/agenda/toggle',   to: 'meetings#toggle_agenda',  as: 'toggle_agenda'
    get '/minutes/toggle',  to: 'meetings#toggle_minutes', as: 'toggle_minutes'
  end
  get 'search', to: 'search#index', as: 'search'
  post 'versions/:id/revert', to: 'versions#revert', as: 'revert_version'

  root 'meetings#index'
end
```

### Ideas

- Could I have some sort of a cacheing issue with Travis since I just changed Legislation to Bill?
- Could this be a namespace issue between my API and default namespaces (I don't think so because Bills is the only problem)
- Is there a typo I missed?

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. I vote to close it as off-topic. Because it is StackOverflow Rules.

Comment: It's not exactly a typographical error; it was a capitalization issue, but that capitalization issue was cause by the way Git handles folder tracking. That said, if it is off-topic, I'd be happy to delete it as well.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out right after I posted. Why couldn't this have happened several hours ago? :( I'll leave this question up in case others have the same issue.

**Git doesn't track folders like it tracks files.** I checked my repository on GitHub, and the views are under /app/views/**B**ills there; I guess when I changed it during the refactoring, that didn't get pushed because it's a folder.

I fixed it by renaming the local file to Bills and them moving all contents from Bills (old folder) to bills (a new folder). ([more detail](http://www.patrick-wied.at/blog/rename-files-and-folders-with-git))